# How to handle error 302 in the scrapy shell

Tags: scrapy

I' trying to scrape a page I'm getting redirected, I try setting an user agent but it didn't work either.

I saw this in other question:

```
meta = {'dont_redirect': True,'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]}
```

How can I test that in the scrapy shell?

Answer (score 1):

When using `scrapy shell`, the simplest way is probably to just disable `RedirectMiddleware` with a `REDIRECT_ENABLED=0` setting on the command line.

Compare this, disabling redirections altogether:

```
$ scrapy shell -s REDIRECT_ENABLED=0
2016-02-09 10:16:27 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-02-09 10:16:27 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-02-09 10:16:27 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'REDIRECT_ENABLED': '0', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter'}
2016-02-09 10:16:30 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-02-09 10:16:32 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
HttpAuthMiddleware, 
DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, 
UserAgentMiddleware,
RetryMiddleware,
DefaultHeadersMiddleware,
MetaRefreshMiddleware,
HttpCompressionMiddleware,
CookiesMiddleware,
ChunkedTransferMiddleware,
DownloaderStats
2016-02-09 10:16:33 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-02-09 10:16:33 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-02-09 10:16:33 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-02-09 10:16:39 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
```

(you can notice that `RedirectMiddleware` is not in the list of "Enabled downloader middlewares")

with the default :

```
$ scrapy shell
2016-02-09 10:17:18 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-02-09 10:17:18 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-02-09 10:17:18 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter'}
2016-02-09 10:17:19 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-02-09 10:17:19 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
HttpAuthMiddleware,
DownloadTimeoutMiddleware,
UserAgentMiddleware,
RetryMiddleware,
DefaultHeadersMiddleware,
MetaRefreshMiddleware,
HttpCompressionMiddleware,
RedirectMiddleware,
CookiesMiddleware,
ChunkedTransferMiddleware,
DownloaderStats
2016-02-09 10:17:19 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-02-09 10:17:19 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-02-09 10:17:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-02-09 10:17:19 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
```